# How to cast String type to array of struct with ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a topic in Kafka which have a schema like:

```
    Name              Type
    ID               STRING
   ORDER_STATUS       INTEGER
   ORDER_ITEM_JSON    STRING
```

ORDER_ITEM_JSON is a string of items itself:

```
 "ORDER_ITEM_JSON":"[{\"item_id\":\"943\",\"category_id_fk\":\"42\",\"item_count\":\"1\",\"item_price\":55900,\"item_price_without_discount\":55900},{\"item_id\":\"1235\",\"category_id_fk\":\"42\",\"item_count\":\"1\",\"item_price\":25500,\"item_price_without_discount\":25500},{\"item_id\":\"1250\",\"category_id_fk\":\"42\",\"item_count\":\"1\",\"item_price\":37500,\"item_price_without_discount\":37500}]"
```

How can I cast this string field to an array of struct in ksql?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-create the stream with `ARRAY<STRUCT` already defined rather than cast afterwards.

Examples on dealing with nested json

- https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/working-with-nested-json/ksql.html
- https://rmoff.net/2020/05/26/working-with-json-nested-arrays-in-ksqldb-example/

Comment: I want to create another stream from this stream and convert the string to Array<struct>. but the created new stream does not show any data like its empty although it is not empty

Comment: But your original data isn't really "a string". So, why not start with the correct data from the beginning?

Comment: The original data from database is string, I tried to make the stream as struct but whenever I do that after selecting the new stream it does not show me anything although the topic is not empty.

Comment: By default, queries start at the end of the topic. You need to [`SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';`](https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1/), and/or use `PRINT`, not `SELECT` to simply see topic data... Besides, the source of the data doesn't matter. Creating a new casted stream from an existing stream will need to run the exact same code as creating a formatted stream from an existing topic

Comment: I think that I found the problem. this field is not an object by the time transferred to Kafka topic it is defined as String and because of that, I can not cast it to struct! I tried to use jsonextraxtfield but now the problem is that I have an array and I can not extract all fields because I do not know how many items are in every array.

Comment: But you never needed to cast as a Struct. It's an `ARRAY<STRUCT`, and you shouldn't need it's size. You can use EXPLODE function to get all array elements, as shown in the links

Comment: Array<Struct does not work in my case it can not desrialize the string field into array<struct, my field is like : [{\item_id\:10,\categoryId\:90}]